# Why do i have no search results after indexing magento 4.1.1.1?

Tags: magento, indexing

i use magento 4.1.1.1
After i have indexed magento,i cant see the product in search results and in the slideshow on the homepage?
Can someone help me with this annoying problem

Comment: Which version of Magento?  The latest version of Community is 1.8?

Comment: Make sure the values you are searching for are a part of the attribute data setup to be included in the search indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to resolve your issue

1 ) whatever you find Keyword, Suppose You Searched Keyword as "green" and "green" is value of color attribute then Go to 
  Catalog->Manage Attributes->Edit your attribute
  check there in Frontend Porperties Tab
  "Use in Quick Search" option must set "yes"

2 ) reindexing from backend

3 ) Go to var/cache folder and delate all folders.

Hope this help you..